# How to build C program that emedded Lua

Tags: c, lua

I'm learning how to embed Lua into C, and start with a simple example:

demo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>

int main (void) {
    char buff[256];
    int error;
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();   /* opens Lua */
    luaopen_base(L);             /* opens the basic library */
    luaopen_table(L);            /* opens the table library */
    luaopen_io(L);               /* opens the I/O library */
    luaopen_string(L);           /* opens the string lib. */
    luaopen_math(L);             /* opens the math lib. */

    while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin) != NULL) {
        error = luaL_loadbuffer(L, buff, strlen(buff), "line") ||
            lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
        if (error) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
            lua_pop(L, 1);  /* pop error message from the stack */
        }
    }

    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

======

My Local environment:

```
evans@master:~/codebase/demo/lua$ sudo dpkg -L liblua5.2-dev
/.
/usr
/usr/include
/usr/include/lua5.2
/usr/include/lua5.2/lua.h
/usr/include/lua5.2/luaconf.h
/usr/include/lua5.2/lualib.h
/usr/include/lua5.2/lauxlib.h
/usr/include/lua5.2/lua.hpp
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblua5.2.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/lua5.2.pc
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/liblua5.2-dev
/usr/share/doc/liblua5.2-dev/copyright
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblua5.2.so
```

Then:

```
gcc -o demo demo.c -llua5.2
demo.c:3:17: fatal error: lua.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I also tried `-llua5`, `-llua` and all failed.

======
Finally I found a solution:

```
gcc -o demo demo.c -I/usr/include/lua5.2 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblua5.2.a -lm
```

**But I couldn't figure out why I cannot do that as I usual.**

Comment: If you're using Lua 5.2 then this code will compile but not work as you expect because the luaopen_* functions that open the standard libraries no longer define them as global variables. Use luaL_openlibs instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to either specify the actual path to the header file:

```
#include <lua5.2/lua.h>
```

or use `-I/usr/include/lua5.2`, like you already figured out. When you attempt to include `<lua.h>`, the compiler only looks for it at `/usr/include/lua.h` (and a few other places that don't matter here).

Answer (score 2):

Copy all your files from /usr/include/lua*.*  to /usr/include/

Comment: This is a bad idea. In particular, if you have two programs that use different versions of Lua, you can't do it this way for both.